CsvHelper.Excel.ExcelWriter doesn't write on MemoryStream
I'm using CsvHelper.Excel.ExcelWriter class from Nuget Pack (CsvHelper.Excel.Core).
It works if I only try to write on FileStream, but it doens't on MemoryStream.
It Works
 using (var w = new CsvHelper.Excel.ExcelWriter("C:\\temp\\test.xlsx", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
 {
     await w.WriteRecordsAsync<MyItem>(items);
     w.Dispose();
 }

It doesn't work
 var mm = new MemoryStream();
 var w = new CsvHelper.Excel.ExcelWriter(mm, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, true);
 await w.WriteRecordsAsync<MyItem>(items);
 mm.Flush();
 w.Dispose();

Any suggestions?

as is the code flushes the memorystream.   Have you tried mm.Position=0; instead?  What are you doing with the memory?

MemoryStream is empty, Position is 0, Length also. Simply, it doesn't work. It's a bug.
